# Nikon D7100 - faulty LCD or mainboard?

Tags: nikon, equipment-damage, lcd, rear-lcd, nikon-d7100

LCD on my Nikon D7100 is not always working. Like 99% of time not working, then it starts semi-working until it doesn't. I read that there are two options why. It could be because of a faulty LCD or something on the main board (Voltage regulator?).

[image: faulty lcd img]

[This is what it looks like from the time it was semi-working](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzAXQHhMLNw), but after I disassembled it has never work again.

Connections of ribbon cables were fine. I tried re-attaching them, but no luck. I also applied pressure on multiple spots of LCD/backlight, again no luck.

Is it the LCD or the motherboard?

Comment: Looks like the LCD. Guess the screen would not work at all if the mainboard was dead but its just a guess.

Comment: But it sometimes works, so maybe not completely faulty voltage regulator or something. I just don't want to spend money on spare part and then discover that it's not the problem :/

Comment: when does it work? when it's hot after use? To me, that looks like a poor connection. You can get an external monitor made for video to "replace" it without as much risk or effort as a repair would imply.

Comment: @dandavis no pattern for when it works. The camera/LCD is never hot unless left on the sun.. I disassembled it and checked, cleaned them, connected/disconnected multiple times, tried wiggle it.. I don't understand what you mean by the external monitor. Link?

Comment: the camera has HDMI output right? they sell portable little (3-6") HDMI monitors, around $100-$200 on amazon; might be worth it if only the LCD is bad...

Comment: The LCD OEM spare part is cheaper, but if it is mainboard that's another story and that is my dilemma :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I tried my luck and bought whole new LCD..and it WORKS. So mainboard is ok.

Looks like it was a problem with moisture/water problem. It's at the bottom of the camera and maybe old seal around the LCD was not perfect. Last time it was working I visited seaside..

If you are unsure, you can remove LCD and check it thoroughly..look for rust/water damage.

[image: lcd ribbon cable rust]